# "Shared to other computers" not working on Lubuntu 18.04 and up

Tags: networking, lubuntu, internet, ethernet

I have a laptop with a WiFi card, and an ethernet port. I also have a desktop with only an ethernet port.

On Lubuntu 16.04.1 I could give my desktop internet access by going to `Edit connections` (`nm-connection-editor`), `Wired Connection`, and then, in the IPv4 and IPv6 tab, setting the drop-down box to `Shared with other computers`. This worked like it should.
I recently tried a fresh install with Lubuntu 18.10, and I couldn't share my internet any more. I then installed Lubuntu 18.04.1 (which I am on now), and it still doesn't work.

When I made a live USB with Lubuntu 16.04.1, and boot it, it **does** work.

I am using a standard Ethernet cable, not a crossover cable.

After installing `dnsmasq`:

```
wessel@Asp-One:~$ ps auxc | grep -i dns
nobody 7199 0.0 0.3 10156 3592 ? S 18:04 0:00 dnsmasq`
```

Running `cat /etc/dnsmasq.conf | grep -v "#"` gives exactly nothing (yes, I added the pipe myself).

Running `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` gives

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 69 jan 12 14:05 /etc/resolv.conf
```

Running `cat /etc/resolv.conf` gives

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search fritz.box
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

Running `ps auxc | grep -i resolv`gives

```
systemd+  9415  0.0  0.1  10652  1760 ?        Ss   jan11   0:00 systemd-resolve
```

After installing `net-tools`, running `ifconfig` gives

```
enp1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.42.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.42.0.255
        inet6 fe80::8ecf:c89a:c895:6866  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 70:5a:b6:fb:d3:46  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1019  bytes 95909 (95.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1468  bytes 1690147 (1.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 11  collisions 0
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 3888  bytes 323853 (323.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3888  bytes 323853 (323.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
wlp2s0b1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.178.66  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.178.255
        inet6 2001:983:f1c:1:37c0:bfe1:39bf:f27  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::60ad:efe7:b5a0:b86b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2001:983:f1c:1:30ef:b8f6:d3de:dbd5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether c4:46:19:21:58:61  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 186393  bytes 226214669 (226.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 63400  bytes 8820907 (8.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The desktop does get an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.

Running `cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` gives

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Comment: Hmmm.... I'm probably out to lunch, but I wonder if 18.04 broke auto-crossover for your NIC... if you're just using a standard ethernet cable to connect the two machines, try a crossover cable just for grins.

Comment: I am indeed using a standard Ethernet cable, I'll edit my question. I currently don't have a crossover cable, sadly.

Comment: Is the desktop obtaining an IP address with your current config? Do you have `dnsmasq` installed and configured? `ps auxc | grep -i dns`. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: Sounds like a bug or a regression to me. bugs are off topic here.

Comment: @GamingWessel hmm ok, well, it *might* be worth a [$5 experiment](https://www.amazon.com/Monoprice-Cat6-Ethernet-Patch-Cable/dp/B009GUMDGO), I dunno.

Comment: @heynnema When the Ethernet cable is connected, running `ps auxc | grep -i dns` gives:


`wessel@Asp-One:~$ ps auxc | grep -i dns`
`nobody    7199  0.0  0.3  10156  3592 ?        S    18:04   0:00 dnsmasq`.

Without Ethernet cable, it returns nothing.


(Sorry about being late btw)

Comment: @GamingWessel ok, thanks. You DO have dnsmasq running. Please edit your question and show me the output of `cat /etc/dnsmasq.conf` and `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and `ps auxc | grep -i resolv` and `ifconfig`. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @GamingWessel also... is the computer with the ethernet port getting an IP address?

Comment: @GamingWessel you should probably also show me `cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`. Thanks.

Comment: @heynnema gotcha

Comment: @GamingWessel please see my answer. It's a little complicated, so note the first line. Report back.

Comment: @user698002 This is working on modern Linux Mint (tested versions 18 and 19). Perhaps consider giving that a shot if Lubuntu is still messing with you.

Answer (score 0):

## PLEASE READ THE ENTIRE ANSWER, AND UNDERSTAND IT, BEFORE MAKING ANY CHANGES.

DNS/DHCP is kind of messed up in 18.xx.

---

I had you install `dnsmasq` mostly for its DHCP server. Some configuration may be required in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`. You'll have to check that it correctly identifies your ethernet port **enp1s0**, as it's probably currently set to **eth0**.

Of course, with recent versions of Ubuntu, they came up with this "easier/better" way to name comm ports... in your case... **enp1s0** and **wlp2s0b1**. Not very user-friendly. If you'd like to revert to their original style names of **eth0** and **wlan0**, you can make the following change...

Edit `/etc/default/grub` and find the line that has "quiet splash", and change it to "quiet splash net.ifnames=0", then do `sudo update-grub`, and `reboot`.

---

Your `/etc/resolv.conf` file is incorrect. You have a hard-wired file, and it should be a symlink to one of two places.

`sudo mv /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.OLD` # rename the current resolv.conf

With dnsmasq running, and doing DNS, it should probably be like this...

`sudo ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf` # create a new symlink

With systemd-resolve running, and doing DNS, it should probably be like this...

`sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf` # create a new symlink

---

But there's a problem. When dnsmasq AND systemd-resolve are running at the same time, they tend to step on each others toes, and DNS resolution gets even more wonky. To cure that, we tell systemd-resolve to back off, and let dnsmasq handle DNS.

**Regarding `dnsmasq` and `systemd-resolved`...**

Do a `ps auxc | grep -i dns` and `ps auxc | grep -i resolv` and look for `dnsmasq` and `systemd-resolved`, and if both are running, you need to disable the DNS part of `systemd-resolved` by editing `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` and...

change:

```
#DNSStubListener=yes
```

to:

```
DNSStubListener=no
```

then restart systemd-resolve and dnsmasq, or reboot.

---

You **may** also need to edit `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`. Edit the file and add a `dns=` line, like so...

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
dns=dnsmasq (or dns=default would probably work also)
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

---

On both computers, you should be able to execute both of the following commands to assure that DNS resolution is working correctly...

`host 8.8.8.8`

`host www.ebay.com`

---

Lastly, you need to monitor the contents of the two resolv.conf files that I noted earlier. Then decide which of the above symlinks that you need to recreate. If everything is working correctly, one of resolv.conf should probably contain 192.168.x.1, the address of the DNS server in your router, or x.x.x.x, the address of some other external DNS server. They probably should not contain 127.0.0.1 or 127.0.0.53.

---

Note: You may need to make some/all of these changes on the 2nd computer, if it's running 18.xx.

---

If all of this is a little confusing, it is. Ask more questions if you need to.

Comment: Thanks! I'll read it thoroughly and try it tomorrow or smth (also, I'm not very eager to mess with the DNS confs, because I tried setting up dnscrypt-proxy, and it messed up name resolution...)

Comment: @GamingWessel was installing dnscrypt-proxy what broke all of this? Did you uninstall it? That's probably why my answer is so long/detailed.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was unclear. I messed around with dnscrypt-proxy **before** I did a fresh install. It should not be around.

Comment: @GamingWessel so where do we stand right now? Is it still not sharing? Did you do any/all of my answer? Report back to "@heynnema"

Comment: @GamingWessel status please

Comment: Sorry, been busy lately. I'll try to get to it today.